# Searching with synonym in elastic search

Tags: php, magento, elasticsearch, synonym

I am implementing search with synonym.
        These are changes for searching with synonym.
        This is my setting in index. I used bubble search extension for that and modified that code.

```
$indexSettings['analysis']['analyzer'] = array(
                'std' => array( 
                'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                'char_filter' => 'html_strip', // strip html tags
                'filter' => array('standard', 'elision', 'asciifolding',                             'lowercase', 'stop', 'length'),
                ),
                'keyword' => array(
                    'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
                    'filter' => array('asciifolding', 'lowercase'),
                ),
                'keyword_prefix' => array(
                    'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
                    'filter' => array('asciifolding', 'lowercase', 'edge_ngram_front'),
                ),
                'text_prefix' => array(
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'char_filter' => 'html_strip', // strip html tags
                    'filter' => array('standard', 'elision', 'asciifolding', 'lowercase', 'stop', 'edge_ngram_front'),
                ),
                'text_suffix' => array(
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'char_filter' => 'html_strip', // strip html tags
                    'filter' => array('standard', 'elision', 'asciifolding', 'lowercase', 'stop', 'edge_ngram_back'),
                ),
/*This is my analyzer for synonym*/
                'synonym' => array(
                    'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                    'type' => 'custom',
                    // 'char_filter' => 'html_strip', // strip html tags
                    'filter' => array('synonym','standard', 'elision', 'asciifolding', 'lowercase', 'stop',"kstem", "length" )
                ),

            );

    $indexSettings['analysis']['filter'] = array(
                'edge_ngram_front' => array(
                    'type' => 'edgeNGram',
                    'min_gram' => 2,
                    'max_gram' => 10,
                    'side' => 'front',
                ),
                'edge_ngram_back' => array(
                    'type' => 'edgeNGram',
                    'min_gram' => 2,
                    'max_gram' => 10,
                    'side' => 'back',
                ),
                'stop' => array(
                    'type' => 'stop',
                    'stopwords' => '_none_',
                ),
                'length' => array(
                    'type' => 'length',
                    'min' => 2,
                ),
/*This is filter for synonym */
                'synonym' => array(
                    'type' => 'synonym',
                    'expand' => true,
                    'synonyms_path' => 'synonyms.txt',
                ),
      );
     $properties[$key]['analyzer'] = 'synonym';
```

I am getting result but not up to mark.
        eg lkjhgf => arylacetamide deacetylase like 3
        If i search for lkjhgf then it will give result for 
        arylacetamide deacetylase like 1
        arylacetamide deacetylase like 2
        arylacetamide deacetylase like 3
        arylacetamide deacetylase like 4

```
    I want exact match and my fuzzy login is also disabled.
```